# Mysqli_insert_id() returning absolutely nothing after successful insert into db. Why?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

**I have seen other questions but none resolved my issue**

**The auto-increment id has no default value and is a PRIMARY KEY**

So I execute a query in AJAX with data posted and it inserts fine. The function even has to send an email once the query has been run and it does that with ease.

But, I also want to get the **INSERT** `id` of the column inserted so I can use it to **UPDATE** it further in the future if the user plans to do so. I'm having trouble as the function `mysqli_insert_id()` returns nothing. Not zero. **Nothing.**

So, why?

This is my query (it works):

```
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $model_name = $_POST['model_name'];
    $problem_name = $_POST['problem_name'];
    $package_name = $_POST['package_name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO ext_orders (`date`, `name`, `address`, `phone`, `email`, `product`, `problem`, `package`, `addons`, `price`) VALUES ('".date("Y/m/d")."', '".$name."', '".$address."', '".$phone."', '".$email."', '".$model_name."', '".$problem_name."', '".$package_name."', 'No', ".intval($price).")";
```

.. and then within an if statement...

```
if(mysqli_query($link, $query)){
```

within the `if` statement, the first thing it does is..

```
$latest_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
```

and then it ends the script with..

```
die($latest_id);
```

and when I alert the `data` returned within jQuery AJAX, it's just blank with no content whatsoever. Any suggestions/solutions?

Comment: Is the query actually inserting data into the database?

Comment: what is the output after using `print_r($latest_id);` before `die()`? And i suggest you to use Prepare Statement to do query request which can prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: The query may fail because of invalid syntax, as you do not escape the variables with `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov like I said though, the data was inserted.

Comment: @JackyShek That worked. For some reason print_r() worked unlike die (). Leave it as an answer.

Comment: I think it has a result but since it is integer will not displayed in `die()` instead of `die($latest_id);` just `var_dump($latest_id);` the `die()` will work if data is string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't display because `die()` accept only string/message parameter  but you pass an integer instead

> die(message)
>
> message    Required. Specifies the message or status number to write before exiting the script. The status number will not be written to the output.

it should be

```
die((string)$latest_id);
```

Comment: Worked! Better yet, print_r () worked too. But in this case I want the script to end at that point so this is more applicable in these circumstances. +1

Comment: yep. use `var_dump` or `print_r` instead of `die` if you really wanted to debug data